# Why Spark implements its own ClassLoader?

Tags: apache-spark, classloader, urlclassloader

In org.apache.spark.util, I found two ClassLoader implements: `MutableURLClassLoader` & `ChildFirstURLClassLoader`, is there some significance to use these two compared to `AppClassLoader` ?